# Serilog won't destructure collections of objects

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, serilog, destructuring

MVC Core web service project, using AspNetCore 2.0.0 and Serilogger 2.1.1.

When calling Serilog to log a collection/IEnumerable/List of objects, all it does is list out the object types. If we loop through the items in the collection and log them independently, Serilog destructures them fine and they appear correctly in our logs.

Basic code sample:

```
List<MyResponse> results = ValidateResourceCollection(events);
_logger.LogInformation("EventController.Post response {@results}", results);
```

And we'll get a log message like this:

```
2018-06-11 10:53:35.952 -04:00 [Information] EventController.Post response "Blah.Models.Response.MyResponse, Blah.Models.Response.MyResponse"
```

Is there a way to get Serilog to destructure this list correctly? 
I tried fixing this by implementing a IDestructuringPolicy, but that only gets called if there is a single object to destructure. If a collection of objects is used as a parameter, the IDestructuringPolicy is never called.

Comment: Serilog will call the `ToString()` method when an object is used as a parameter, so if you override it on type `MyResponse` you should be able to format the text as desired.

Comment: Not going to work. Don't want to have to override the ToString method on all the various types of collections we're using. Out objects destructure just fine when we log then alone. An IEnumerable<someType> won't.

Comment: Let me clarify... I really don't want to put an overriden ToString method on all the models we have, especially when it works just fine if we log the list items separately. Shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: Take a look at [Customizing the stored data](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data#customizing-the-stored-data) documentation in the wiki.

Comment: That example won't work since our types are varied, and we don't want to put all of the transformations in our startup code. As I stated above, we added a IDestructuringPolicy implementation, but it doesn't get called for collections. It only gets called for single elements.

Comment: Maybe open an issue on the [Serilog repo](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues) asking why `IDestructuringPolicy` isn't working on collections.  It maybe your configuration or a bug, but hard to say unless you can provide some skeleton code.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll try to put together a sample and post a bug there.

Comment: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1182

Answer (score 0):

You can use a destructuring policy in order to log a collection of objects:

```cs
public class CollectionDestructuringPolicy<T> : IDestructuringPolicy
{
    public bool TryDestructure(object value, ILogEventPropertyValueFactory propertyValueFactory,
        out LogEventPropertyValue result)
    {

        switch (value)
        {
            case City city:
                result = Destruct(city,propertyValueFactory);
                return true;
            case ICollection<T> collection:
                result = Destruct(collection,propertyValueFactory);
                return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    private static LogEventPropertyValue Destruct(object collectionItem, ILogEventPropertyValueFactory propertyValueFactory)
    {
        var collectionItemPropertiesNamePerValue = new List<(string propertyName, object propertyValue)>();
        var collectionItemProperties = collectionItem.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
        collectionItemProperties.ForEach(p => collectionItemPropertiesNamePerValue.Add((propertyName:p.Name, propertyValue:p.GetValue(collectionItem))));
        var properties = new List<LogEventProperty>(collectionItemPropertiesNamePerValue.Count);
        collectionItemPropertiesNamePerValue.ForEach(namePerValue =>
            properties.Add(new LogEventProperty(namePerValue.propertyName,
                propertyValueFactory.CreatePropertyValue(namePerValue.propertyValue))));
        LogEventPropertyValue result = new StructureValue(properties);
        return result;
    }

    private static LogEventPropertyValue Destruct(IEnumerable<T> collection,
        ILogEventPropertyValueFactory propertyValueFactory)
    {
        var elements = collection.Select(e => propertyValueFactory.CreatePropertyValue(e, true));
        LogEventPropertyValue result = new SequenceValue(elements);
        return result;
    }
}
```

```cs
//In Logger Factory:
public static class LoggerFactory
{
    public static Logger Create()
    {
        return new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .Destructure.With<CollectionDestructuringPolicy<City>>()
            .CreateLogger();
    }
}
```

RMK. an accomplished asp.net core solution [sample](https://github.com/georgekargakis/SerilogDestructCollectionType)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but might be still useful to someone: Serilog method `ForContext` has an optional flag `destructureObjects`, which be default is `false`. Setting it to `true` will deconstruct even a collection of objects:

```
List<MyResponse> results = ValidateResourceCollection(events);
_logger.ForContext("Results", results, destructureObjects: true).Information("EventController.Post response returned some results");
```